# send two different forms in one click using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i was trying to send two different forms in one click. the first form will use to send form_multipart and the other will be through javascript. why javascript? because it is the only way i know that sends a batchinsert form in codeigniter. the two works fine if executed independently. how would you suggest to properly combine the forms in the right way? do i need to  send the code?

View

```
<?php 
    $attributes = array("name" => "signupform");
    $hidden = array('userId' => 'userId', 'userType' => 'client', 'branchId' => 'CDO1', 'position' => 'none', 'userfile' => 'userfile');
    echo form_open_multipart("Client_Dashboard/signupPost", $attributes, $hidden);
?>
```

Controller
public function signupPost()
    {

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run('signup') == FALSE) {
        //fails wont continue to next page
        $this->signup_view();
    } else {
        //insert data into the database
        $data = array(
            'userId' => $this->input->post('userId'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'emailAddress' => $this->input->post('emailAddress'),
            'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
            'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
            'middleInitial' => $this->input->post('middleInitial'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
            'lengthOfResidency' => $this->input->post('lengthOfResidency'),
            'contactNo' => $this->input->post('contactNo'),
            'dateOfBirth' => $this->input->post('dateOfBirth'),
            'maritalStatus' => $this->input->post('maritalStatus'),
            'citizenship' => $this->input->post('citizenship'),
            'noOfDependents' => $this->input->post('noOfDependents'),
            'userType'  => $this->input->post('userType'),
            'position'  => $this->input->post('position'),
            'branchId'  => $this->input->post('branchId'),
            'UserFile' => $this->uploadImage()
            );
        //user data has successfully signed up
        $this->User->signup_client($data);
        redirect('http://localhost/***/index.php/****','refresh');
    }
}
```

[image]

View

```
<script>
    ("#frm_submit").on('submit', function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php //echo base_url() ?>index.php/Client_Dashboard/income_batchInsert',
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: $("#frm_submit").serialize()
                 }).always(function (response){
                     var r = (response.trim());
                    if(r == 1){
                         $(".alert-success").show();
                    }
                     else{
                         $(".alert-danger").show();
                    }
                 });
             });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function income_batchInsert()
    {
        $result = $this->foo_inc->income_batchInsert($_POST);
            if($result){
                echo 1;
            }
            else{
                echo 0;
            }
            exit;
    }
```

Model

```
public function income_batchInsert($data)
    {
        $count = 1;

        for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){
            $entries[] = array(
                'SourceIncome'=>$data['SOI'][$i],
                'NameOfFirm'=>$data['name'][$i],
                'Position'=>$data['postion'][$i],
                'Address'=>$data['addrss'][$i],
                'ContactNo'=>$data['telNo'][$i],
                'MonthlyIncome'=>$data['MI'][$i],
                );
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('income', $entries); 
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes show your code obviously.

Comment: What is a batch insert form? No such thing in html. If it was me I would use one form for all of this

Comment: your batch insert also can submit without js

Comment: @charlietfl this is a codeigniter syntax for multiple or array insertion that can be seen in my income tab image

Comment: @FastSnail do you have any suggestion or blog about sending it and appending it the same time without using js?

Comment: @HanthonyTagam submit one by ajax and wait for response after that submit other form.

Comment: @HanthonyTagam " sending it and appending it the same time" you mean without refresh? if you wnt to do it without refreshing use ajax for both forms.what is the problem?

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158210/discussion-between-hanthony-tagam-and-fast-snail).

Comment: @FastSnail how do you expect me to do it? do you mean i need to send the ajax form first for income and the whole form for personal info?